# To store images in file system, database, or blob?

Tags: image, asp.net-core, storage

I have roughly 600 static images that I need to store and use for my web app and I was wondering what kind of options I have for this application.

What is the typical procedure?
What are my options, and what are the pro's and con's of each?

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store static resources that you want to serve from your site somewhere under the `wwwroot` folder. I recommend putting them in an `images` subfolder, but you can use whatever organization works for you. There are many reasons why it can be worthwhile to use a Content Delivery Network (CDN) for serving your static resources, including scripts, stylesheets, and images, in which case you might want to store your images there. For example Amazon CloudFront is an inexpensive CDN service you can use for this purpose. This will speed up your page load times since the images will load in parallel with your site's assets, it will reduce load on your server, and the CDN server will host the images on edge servers that are geographically close to the client (so clients on the other side of the world from your server will get the files faster than if they loaded them from your server).

Overall this isn't so much an ASP.NET Core question, but a general web site question. ASP.NET Core will serve static resources (as long as you have the static files middleware installed), but other than that it doesn't have a lot to do with it. Just put the files under `wwwroot` and you're good to go unless you think it's worth using a CDN.

Comment: So, are you saying that storing 600+ images in wwwroot doesn't have any downsides?

Comment: I wouldn't bat an eye at that, no. Use some folders to organize them if necessary, but otherwise it should be fine. What issues are you worried about?

Comment: The file system is one of the better places to store files, as opposed to, say, a database. Like most performance issues, it's usually best not to prematurely optimize. Do the easiest thing that ships working code fastest, but in a clean way that you can easily modify later. In this case, if you do find that serving files from the server is causing some kind of issues, consider moving them to a CDN. I think the bigger issue you'll find is optimizing the page load time for your users (which a CDN helps), not any kind of intrinsic perf issue on your site.